# Ethereum Pet Shop tutorial - ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop) to learn how to code a dapp. I put together this .sol code (well, copy/pasted...):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
address[16] public adopters;
}

// Adopting a pet
function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
  require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

  adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

  return petId;
}

// Retrieving the adopters
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
  return adopters;
}
```

and there's another file that was already there. When I run the truffle compile command I see the following:

```
ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
^------^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.1.34 (core: 5.1.34)
Node v12.18.2
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions must be within the `contract` scope:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
  address[16] public adopters;


  // Adopting a pet
  function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

    adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

    return petId;
  }

  // Retrieving the adopters
  function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
    return adopters;
  }

} // <= closing brace
```